# Table CSS styling | Borders

Tags: html, css, border

I really need some help with CSS.

I'm trying to style a table and I'm having difficulties adding borders.

Here's the table style I'm going for (Photoshopped): https://ibb.co/hFkCkDg

Adding a border around the table is simple:

```
.table-class {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/Fs6qsNv

To add the separating lines inside the table I need to add a top or bottom border to the rows in the table. Rows are `tr` elements. By default a `tr` element of a table does not accept borders. So in order to overcome this I added `{border-collapse: collapse !important;}` to the whole table which allowed me to add borders to rows, but it messed up the border around the whole table. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/Vgfq9jp

Because of `{border-collapse: collapse !important;}`, the properties `border`, `padding`, `border-radius` don't work for the table.

Which means I can either add a border around the whole table or add the separating lines, but not both.

How can I achieve the look I'm going for?

Comment: Please try always to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go using flexbox, and setting `flex: 1` or `flex-grow: 1` to the **first child** of each *"row"*:

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font: 16px/1.4 'Varela Round', sans-serif; padding: 20px;} /* DEMO ONLY */

/*
  Order
*/

.Order {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 25px
}

.Order-price {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.Order-price > * {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.Order-price > *:first-child{
  flex: 1;
}

.Order-price:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.Order-price--sub {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.Order-price--tot {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/*
  Colors
*/

.color-lighter {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="Order">
  <div class="Order-price">
    <span class="color-lighter">Custom Tatoo Design - Small &times; 1</span>
    <span><s class="color-lighter">$99.00</s> <b>$80.00</b></span>
  </div>
  <div class="Order-price Order-price--sub">
    <span>Subtotal</span>
    <span>$80.00</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Order-price Order-price--tot">
    <span>Total</span>
    <span><small>USD</small> $80.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @roko, thank you for your answer. I tried using this method. Here's the outcome: [desktop view](https://ibb.co/fqshwCY) & [mobile landscape view](https://ibb.co/Qj6cYFG).  For some reason the product prices get stuck in the middle but I couldn't figure out why. Do you have any idea what might be the issue here? Here's a [link](https://www.mydreamtattoo.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=3981) to my checkout page so you can check the table for yourself. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, so I fixed it but I have no idea why what I did worked. Instead of setting `flex: 1` to the `:first-child` of each product row, I added it to the `:last-child`. I don't know the difference, but it fixed the issue with the product prices. All of the other table rows work with either `:first-child` or `:last-child`, it doesn't seem to make a difference. Also, what does the `*` mean in your CSS code? I also didn't set a `border-bottom: none` to the `:last-child` as it didn't do anything.

Comment: @JOKKER `*` is a wildcard for *All* therefore `.foo > *` means (RtL): *target All Immediate descendants of .foo*. If you inspect Element and highlight the element that has `flex-grow: 1` (or `flex: 1`) you'll see the difference. It's not negligible. For my specfic case I wanted the *first* SPANs to "expand/grow" (pushing the siblings to the far-right), not the second ones. All that matters is that is solves the problem :)

Comment: @JOKKER again... please don't post images if not necessary. I cannot guess what you did by just looking at an image. You can always create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or jsBin of your current minimal example code - if you want to share your current progress!

Answer (score -1):

working with table border is boring, my suggestion is to use the border in  `td/th` elements.

I created this table without style, only solving the problem of borders

```css
   .table-class {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 30px;
    border-spacing: unset;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.table-class thead th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
}

.table-class tbody td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.table-class td:last-child, .table-class th:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}

.table-class th, .table-class td{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-class">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Custom Tattoo Desing - Small x 1</th>
      <th>
        <span><s>$99.00</s></span>
        <span>$80.00</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
      <td>$80.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>USD $80.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```